# 74 Series Logic Power switching with Gnd? (74Hc86)

Tags: power, digital-logic

I'm trying to cut power to the chip to "disable" all outputs without needing to know the input values or changing them. What happens if I use a NPN transistor to let the GND pin float and pull it to GND if the transistor switches on? Would that work? I'm trying to use a npn because my circuit has one unused channel in an ULN2003 and I'm trying to reduce my component count.

Answer (score 2):

The inputs to the chip will remain active and more than likely any "low" inputs will "power" the ground of the 74HC86 via protection diodes on the inputs. I don't think it will work.

Comment: +1. I have seen a "slightly unreliable" TTL circuit where one chip had no ground connection whatsoever. It only malfunctioned when all its inputs were high at the same time! Otherwise the logic levels were none too stable, but good enough for that application.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that's a bad idea is that looking at the [ON Semiconductor 74HC86 Datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/74HC86.REV1.PDF) for example you'll notice that all the maximum and recommended voltages are referenced to ground. When you remove the power ground you have the situation where an input can be at ground, while Vcc is still being applied and that can cause current to leak through the chip along paths not intended.

I'd recommend adding some additional logic to handle the situation properly even though it will increase the part count. You could for example look at a buffer that has an output enable pin, maybe something like a 74HC365.

Also as Wouter has pointed out in a comment even without those limits on the input voltage  the datasheet has a 'recommended operational conditions' section. 0V power is outside those conditions, so you can't expect any specific behavior of the chip without power applied.

Comment: I'd rather use one additional P-channel mos to solve my problem and cut power to everything but thank you two for your input. They should have added an OE pin on the 86 ;)

Comment: @danielheinrich, no problem. Be aware if you did cut both GND and Vcc you still may have the same problem anyway, in that case one input could be low and the other high and cause the same problem. There are also limits about an input not being above Vcc.

Comment: Even without those limits on the input voltage: the datasheet has a 'recommended operational conditions' section. 0V power is outside those conditions, so you can't expect ANY specifc behavior of the chip with 0V power. You can of course try it and see what the chip does, but that is not exactly sound engineering.

Comment: I'm driving a ULN2003 with it to power a unipolar stepper motor. My problem is that if I use the 86 to only need two instead of four digital pins, there is no real "Off" for the motor because some windings are always energized. I'd use the p-ch mosfet to cut power from the motor, not the 74hc86 or the Uln2003.